# How to split a Dataset into training and testing for machine learning?

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset, machine-learning

Suppose I have iris data In the Dataset Format.
[image]

How to split the iris data Into training and testing for Machine learning?

For example,Transform the data for Classify.

Answer (score 16):

Let's use the Titanic dataset

```
tit = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Titanic"}];
```

Let's see it's columns

```
tit[Union, Keys]
```

Let's choose an objective

```
obj = "survived";
```

Let's add an id to each row

```
tit = tit[AssociationThread[Range@Length@#, #] &];
```

Let's create a database that splits the features and objective, to make this general.

```
titSplit = 
  tit[All, <|"Features" -> Values@*KeyDrop[obj], 
    "Objective" -> Key[obj]|>];
```

Let's split the rows arbitrarily to have a test and train set.

```
numTraining = 200;
ids = Range@tit[Length];
testIds = ids~RandomSample~numTraining;
trainIds = ids~Complement~testIds;

titUnclass = titSplit[<|"Test" -> testIds, "Train" -> trainIds|>];
```

Let's train the classifier

```
cfun = titUnclass["Train", Classify@*Values, #Features -> #Objective &];
```

Let's create a new dataset appending the classifications as a column in the Test dataset.

```
titClass = 
  titUnclass[{"Test" -> 
     Query[All, Append[#, <|"Classified as" -> cfun@#Features|>] &]}];
```

Or perhaps just have the results in a separate database `results = titUnclass["Test", All, cfun@#Features &];`

Let's ask for performance measures

```
cfm = titUnclass["Test", 
   ClassifierMeasurements[cfun, #] & @* Values, 
   #Features -> #Objective &];

cfm["Accuracy"]

(* 0.75 *)
```

**Edit**

This is based on the OP @PhilChang nice suggestion in the comments

`RandomSample` works on `Dataset`s

```
rtit = RandomSample@ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Titanic"}];
```

Split

```
obj = "survived"; numTrain = 200;
ctit = rtit[<|"Train" -> (;; numTrain), "Test" -> (numTrain + 1 ;;)|>];
```

Train

```
cfun = ctit["Train", GroupBy[Key[obj] -> KeyDrop[obj]], Values][
   Classify];
```

Measure

```
cfm = ctit["Test", GroupBy[Key[obj] -> KeyDrop[obj]], Values][
   ClassifierMeasurements[cfun, #] &];
cfm["Accuracy"]
```

Comment: I get an `Accuracy` = 0.63. Naive splitting like this is often biased by the dataset layout, eg, look at the distribution of "class": `trainTit[Map[First] /* Counts, "Features"]` --> `"1st" -> 200` versus `testTit[Map[First]...]` --> `"1st" -> 123, "2nd" -> 277, "3rd" -> 709`. Typically, bootstrap or other resampling methods are used to minimize the effects of clustering. Certainly you'd want to randomize the partition.

Comment: @alancalvitti I struggled with posting it `RandomSample`d or not, but I'll edit now. I'll also put both trainTit and testTit inside another database.

Comment: We need to make this easier, probably with a new function. Especially making sure you preserve the frequencies of whatever classes when you do the split.

Comment: Thank you all,I learned a lot from it. For this moment the best way maybe: 1. Random the dataset, randsample = RandomSample @ titanic; 2. get train and test data. train = RandSample[;;3000];test = randomSample[3001;;]; 3. transform the data set for classify use. train = titanic[GroupBy[Key[obj]], All, Values@*Normal@*KeyDrop[obj]];

Comment: If Only Classify accept a Dataset as its argument:Classify[mydataset,y,{x1,x2,...,xp}]

Comment: @PhilChang nice, I hadn't realised `RandomSample` worked with Dataset arguments. I also like your GroupBy obj approach better, since Classify can also take that format as argument! I'll edit

Comment: Functions for working with Datasets to build test sets for statistics/sampling in general would be very useful. This is quite complex for most cases where you have pre-labeled data.

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon given Etienne's comments about Classify performing some internal cross validation in the answer below - isn't there a risk that by performing the splitting (and potentially folding} prior to using Classify that we just do a bad version of something that is already "built in"?    http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67715/how-to-know-the-internal-algorithms-of-functions-like-predict-or-classify

Comment: @GordonCoale You can use the `ValidationSet` option to `Classify` and `Predict` to override our internal cross-validation if you have your own test set. Also, @Rojo, note that in 10.0.2 you can use the `Classify[data -> out]` shorthand to indicate that the column name or number is the one being predicted, so you don't have to split off the features from the output yourself.

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon that's neat, thanks! Nice to see you back around

Comment: The code above does not work for me as of Mathematica 10.0.2 (WIndows 64Bit) - has something changed? The line `titSplit = 
 tit[All, <|"Features" -> Values@*KeyDrop[obj], 
   "Objective" -> Key[obj]|>]` will cause the errors "The argument Identity is not a valid Association or a list of rules." and ""The argument \!\(Values[\(KeyDrop[\"survived\"]\)[Identity]]\) is \
not a valid Association or a list of rules." ? Also the EDIT-section does not work as `ctit = rtit[<|"Train" -> (;; numTrain), "Test" -> (numTrain + 1 ;;)|>]`will cause a Transpose-error.

Comment: How come after all these years, there's no built-in function for such a fundamental machine learning operation?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a resource function now...

https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/TrainTestSplit/