# Rewrite Composition to include Method in Classify?

Tags: function-construction

I was reading [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57249/52355) and thought I would ask a question since it had been asked ~5 years ago. Now there is a line in the answer where it states that to train the classifier, you can use the code:

```
cfun = titUnclass["Train", Classify @* Values, #Features -> #Objective &];
```

I had never seen this "at star" notation before, so I looked it up, and discovered it was called `Composition` (`@*`). Now I know for `Classify` that it can specify several methods, however, written like this, it seems that Mathematica goes through several methods before determining the best to use.

My issue is this: I would like to specify the method, however I do not know enough to figure out how to rewrite this line to do so. I tried

```
cfun = titUnclass["Train", Classify[Values, Method -> "DecisionTree"], #Features -> #Objective &];
```

and

```
Composition[Classify][Values]
```

but received the error (for both)

```
Classify::bdfmt: Argument Values should be a rule, a list of rules, or an association.
```

If someone could point me in the right direction for tackling this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You misread the notation. Look at the result of `FullForm[Classify @* Values]`. Then, look at the result of `(f @* g)[x]`.

Comment: Oh! I see! My mistake. I wrote work around where I use //Normal, but I'm still curious to see how Composition[Classify,Values] would be re-written to include Method.

Comment: Normally, the function concerned would be something like `Classify[Values[stuff]]`, which you want to modify to `Classify[Values[stuff], Method -> "DecisionTree"]`. Since you're calling it inside a `Dataset[]`, you'd need to use `#` and `&` somewhere in there.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment.

Comment: does `cfun = titUnclass["Train", (Classify[#,Method->"DecisionTree"]&)@*Values, #Features -> #Objective &];` work?

Comment: @kglr I just tried it out and yes it did!

Comment: If you add that as an answer, I will accept it. It is much nicer than my work around, where I got the data from the column, used Normal, wrote it as a in the form {point}->1, etc, then passed into classify... etc etc. You get the idea. I was thinking surely there must be a better way to do this, haha.

Comment: Jomy, glad it worked. I posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
cfun = titUnclass["Train", (Classify[#, Method->"DecisionTree"]&) @* Values,
   #Features -> #Objective &];
```

Comment: `titUnclass["Train", Classify[Values[#], Method -> "DecisionTree"] &, #Features -> #Objective &]` was the result I was hoping OP would think up, but oh well.